# Vs code API- работа с git

Tags: javascript, git, visual-studio-code, git-commit

Я пишу расширения для code для отслеживания продуктивности - [productivity-checker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ColorKat.productivity-checker) -
Если кто хочет можете протестировать))

Я хочу добавить в него просмотр коммитов. Например, время, сообщение коммита, ветку и тд.
В документации vs code api вроде ничего такого нет.

Comment: Мне кажется проще всего подсмотреть в конфиге путь к экзешнику гита, и с помощью него получать информацию о коммитах.

Comment: Ну это можно назвать костылем, я думаю